# Integer solutions to $ n^2 + 1 = 2 \times 5^m$

Tags: diophantine-equations

What are the integer solutions to the diophantine equation

$$n^2 + 1 = 2 \times 5 ^m? $$

We have $(n,m) = (3,1), (7, 2) $ as solutions. Are there any more?

---

This seems like it would be a well known diophantine equation, but I can't seem to find any information about it.

Comment: Idea for $m\geq 2$, the last two digits of $2\times 5^m-1$ are $249$. You want to prove that you find perfect squares $n>2$ with these last two digits. For $n>7$, the numbers can have the last three digits $a3$ or $b7$. For $\overline{\dots a3}^2=\overline{\dots a^200}+60a+9$ so $a$ has to be $4$ or $9$ which do not work. For $\overline{\dots b7}^2=\overline{\dots b^200}+140b+49$ so $b$ has to be $0$ which does not work or $5$ which works. I do not know it it helps.

Comment: @Iulia Unfortunately it does not seem likely to be helpful. Hensel's lemma tells us that there will be a solution to the condition, but the issue is that the solution is too large, and hence violates the next condition that we need to check.

Comment: @CalvinLin: It is called a [Ramanujan-Nagell-type equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%E2%80%93Nagell_equation#Equations_of_Ramanujan.E2.80.93Nagell_type) $$x^2+C = AB^m$$ where $A,B,C$ are constants. By a result of Seigel, there should only be a finite number of solutions. (It would have been nice if his proof included an upper bound for $m$.)

Comment: Having just asked a similar question, I found that there are indeed no further solutions, with reference to the paper "On the number of solutions of the generalized Ramanujan-Nagell equation" by Bugeaud and Shorey, and thus note such here.

Comment: The only solutions $(m,n)$ are $\quad(0,\pm1)\quad(1,\pm3)\quad(2,\pm7)$, You can verify this in a spreadsheet using $n = \pm\sqrt{2*5^m - 1}$

Comment: @poetasis How did you check the infinitely many possible values of $(m, n)$ with a spreadsheet?

Comment: @Calvin Lin Your point is well taken. The solutions offered were from a spreadsheet with a limit of $15$ digits. I have no proof that there are no more solutions. I only know that all solutions other than zero have $m$ ending in $3$ or $7$.

Comment: You might try [this paper](http://www.math.tifr.res.in/~saradha/saradharev.pdf)

Answer (score 6):

By factoring the given equation over the Gaussian integers, we are looking for solutions of:
$$a_m=\operatorname{Re}\left((1\pm i)(2+i)^m\right)=\pm 1.\tag{1}$$
It is straighforward to check that $(1)$ is fullfilled by $m=0,m=1$ and $m=2$.

In order that $(1)$ holds, $\frac{\pi}{4}+m\arctan\frac{1}{2}\pmod{2\pi}$ must be close to $0,\pm\frac{\pi}{2}$ or $\pi$.

That happens for $m=15,22,29,36,\ldots$ and many others $m$ such that:
$$\left\{m\cdot\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan\frac{1}{2}\right\}\text{ is close to }\frac{1}{4}\text{ or } 0.\tag{2}$$
where $\{\cdot\}$ stands for the fractional part. So we have that other solutions of $(1)$ *may occur* for $m=q$ or $m=q/4$, where $\frac{p}{q}$ is a convergent of the continued fraction of $\alpha=\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan\frac{1}{2}$ and $4\mid q$ if needed.

The first of such good candidates is $m=83$: in such a case the absolute value of the ratio between the real part and the imaginary part of $(1+i)(2+i)^m$ is something like $0.00175$, but the real part is still a $27$-digits number.

It is reasonable to conjecture that no other solutions exist apart from the trivial ones; however, that looks hard to prove (at least to me) since the continued fraction of $\alpha$ does not have a good structure (like for the golden ratio, the constant $e$ or some values of Bessel's functions).

---

An alternative approach (but not so much) may be to prove by arithmetical arguments that the only solutions of the Pell equations
$$ n^2-2N^2=1,\qquad n^2-10 N^2=1\tag{3}$$
with $N=5^m$ are the trivial ones. That problem depends on the convergents of $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{10}$ that are *way* nicer. It is probably not to difficult to derive an explicit formula for the $5$-adic height of a [lambda number](https://oeis.org/A000129) $P_n$ and deduce that there are a finite number of $N$s of the form $5^m$ that may fulfill $(3)$.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote but your reformulation is not immediately clear.

Comment: @nayrb: I just used the fact that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a Euclidean domain. By factoring the given equation over such a ring, $(1)$ as a reformulation follows immediately.

Comment: @CalvinLin: ok, now fixed.

Comment: The factorization isn't clear and where does the $n$ go?

Comment: And shouldn't the $(2+i)^m$ term be balanced with a $(2-i)^m$ term somewhere, and why take the real part?

Comment: We must have: $$(n+i)(n-i) = (1+i)(1-i)(2+i)^m(2-i)^m,$$ so: $$n+i = (1\pm i)(2+i)^m. $$ We multiply both terms by $-i$ and take the real part.

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense. Might be good to point out you only have a sufficient condition for solutions and not a necessary one to avoid confusion.

Comment: I did think of the Pell's equation, but wasn't able to push through the approach.