# How to determine if the following quadratic equations have solutions in $\mathbb{Q}_5 $ and find approximations

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I am reading about p-adic numbers, just begining on it. I came across this exercise:

Determine if the following equation has solutions in $\mathbb{Q}_5$. If this is the case, produce approximations $a_0 + a_1 5 + a_2 5^2 + a_3 5^3$ modulo $5^4$ in $\mathbb{Z}_5$ of both roots, with $a_i \in \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$

(a) $x^2 − 7 = 0$

(b) $x^2 + x − 7 = 0$

(c) $x^2 − 5^{−3} = 0$

Can someone show me what is the S.O.P (standard operating procedure) here? I t would help if you could do at least one as an example, I think there are two parts,

1. determine if solutions exists in  $\mathbb{Q}_5$ and
2. If they do, find the approximations

Comment: See for example [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3561943/solve-x2-1-in-mathbbq-5).

Comment: Also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/88488/96384 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2298779/96384.