# Why, intuitively, `i` exists on 5-adics, but not on 2-adics?

Tags: complex-numbers, p-adic-number-theory

The square root of -1 exists in 5-adics, but not on 2-adics. I understand this since there is clearly a number that, multiplied by itself, results in `-1`, on p-adics. I also understand why, algebraically, we can't construct such number on 2-adics. What I do not understand is the meaning and intuition behind that. Does that mean that 3-adics work like complex numbers? If we used 5-adics for programming, would we be able to represent complex numbers over the entire complex plane as a single value, rather than two? Why would that be the case?

Comment: You can describe a $3-$adic number with one value? How? Anyway, there isn't even a square root of $-1\pmod 3$.   Maybe you meant $5-$adic?

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88488/square-roots-in-the-p-adics) for some relevant details.

Comment: And [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2309918/on-5-adic-representation-of-square-root-of-1) is a discussion of the $5-$adic square root of $-1$.

Comment: @lulu yes, 5-adic, sorry for the confusion. About your question, can't you represent a 5-adic as an infinite string containing its digit expansion? That's a single number, even though it is infinite. That would be a sensible representation in a lazy programming language, like Haskell. How are p-adics represented usually, in programming? I'm curious.

Comment: You can easily represent a complex number as a single (usually infinite) string of integers, if you really want to.

Comment: you can "approximate" $p$-adics by working in $\Bbb Z/p^n\Bbb Z$ for large $n$

Comment: [here](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01444183/document) is an article on implementations of $p-$adics.

Comment: @lulu great article, thanks

Comment: No problem, glad to have helped.

Comment: To answer the question in the title, it's because the exponent $2$ in $x^2=-1$ is relatively prime to the prime $5$, but not relatively prime to the prime $2$.

Comment: @lulu if I may ask, is there any reason for not representing p-adics as just lazy infinite list of digits? Seems like the idea proposed in the paper is an over-complication. Not sure if I'm missing something.

Comment: It all depends what you want to do.  Taking an element of $\mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z$ for large $n$ as an approximation is fine for most applications.

Comment: "The square root of -1" is not a thing. Not a thing that exists somewhere as such, a thing in itself or so. Rather: Some fields contain square roots of $-1$ (if they do, they usually contain two), and others don't. The field $\mathbb C$ does, the field $\mathbb R$ does not. The field $\mathbb Q_5$ does (and so do infinitely many other $\mathbb Q_p$), the field $\mathbb Q_2$ does not (and neither do infinitely many other $\mathbb Q_p$).

Answer (score 4):

Nothing "works like the complex numbers" in the $p$-adics when you are looking at the fields $\mathbf Q_p$: the complex numbers are algebraically closed, but $\mathbf Q_p$ is very far from being algebraically closed: its algebraic closure is an infinite-degree extension.  Do not try to think of $\mathbf C$ as being like some finite extension of $\mathbf Q_p$.

On the other hand, you could say "every quadratic extension in characteristic $0$ looks like the complexes over the reals" if you are just thinking about the field automorphisms: if $E/F$ is a field extension of degree $2$ then $E = F(\sqrt{d})$ where $d \in F^\times$ is not a square in $F$ and the unique field automorphism of $E$ fixing $F$ is $a + b\sqrt{d} \mapsto a-b\sqrt{d}$ for $a, b \in F$.

Answer (score 1):

In the equation $x^2=-1$ the exponent is a unit in $5$-adics but not $2$-adics. You can lift the additive inverse ordered pair $(2,3\bmod 5)$ by the Hensel process; but if you try it with $(1,1\bmod 2)$ the non-unit exponent, becoming a coefficient upon differentiation, gives a wrong form for the derivative killing the Hensel lift.

The derivative in the $2$-adics case can be fixed if you can ground the solution $\bmod 4$, but this works only when the radicand has residue $1\bmod 8$. Thus you can get $\sqrt{-7}$ in $2$-adics.